# Как изменить или добавить стиль у class если он после обновления рандомный

Tags: javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть сайт, на сайте рандомно при каждом обновлении страницы меняются класс css.
А мне необходимо в блоке div найти скажем эти классы по RegEX и применить к ним свой стиль

```
<div class="ff471a58f f8d4b99e7 yacc1b0f3 gad576820">
тут текст в блоке
</div>
```

я пробовал делать так:

```
div[class^="a"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="b"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="c"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="d"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="e"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="f"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="g"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="h"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="i"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="j"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="k"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="l"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="m"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="n"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="o"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="p"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="q"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="r"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="s"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="t"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="u"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="v"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="w"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="x"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="y"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
div[class^="z"][class$="z"] {display:none !important;}
```

но это не реально, т.к. писать придется много условий. Вот и подумал возможно ли это реализовать через JS

Условие.
Если на странице в class присутствуют рандомные символы по какому нибудь условию, то мы их находим и заменяем на свой класс скажем атрибут display:none.

Comment: Под фразу "рандомные символы" попадает любое имя класса. Любая последовательность символов - это случайность. То, что эта случайность собирается нашим мозгом в слова, это уже частности ) А это ваш сайт?

Comment: Да, сайт мой, но генерация стилей идет от виджета рандомно, и ях не могу скрыть)

Comment: Добавьте какой нибудь атрибут в тег, допустим data-notshow. По данному атрибуту отбирайте и скрывайте.

Comment: покажите код виджета, может получится как-то иначе стили поменять. Что за виджет?

Comment: @SwaD - Скажем такого рода? div[data-notshow^='false']{display:none !important;} ??

Comment: Ну типа того. Можно даже просто проверять наличие атрибута - если есть, скрывать. Можете конечно и значение атрибуту присвоить, но в вашем случае это кажется лишним.

Comment: @SwaD - не получиться. div формируется через script который вставлен на сайте. так что изменить я их не могу(( видимо от через скрипт подгружает - вот итог кода - https://ic.wampi.ru/2022/12/19/code.jpg

Comment: Может `data[data-ad-id] { display: none !important; }`? :p

Comment: @Gelloiss вот код - https://ic.wampi.ru/2022/12/19/code.jpg

Comment: @ΝNL993 - нет, блок не скрылся

Comment: Я имел в виду, как оно реально в исходный код вставляется... А так, еще как вариант можете обращаться к DOM элементам, типа знаете родитель с конкретным id, и знаете весь путь воженности чтобы обратиться к нужному div. Можете на примере кода сказать кто родитель и какому div надо изменить класс - напишу код, если не умеете.

Comment: @Gelloiss т.е. правильно ли я понял сделать примерно следующие:
У родителя нет ни id ни Class
`body > div > div> div> div> div> div > div { display: none !important; }`
скажем считаем кол-во div, и тот которые мне нужен я на нем останавливаюсь и выполняю сценарий css?

и что это? #shadow-root (open)

Comment: Правильно. Но родителю стоит дать id. Тому родителю, в который в вставялете код виджета в исходном коде сайта. Тогда вы легко сможете добраться до нужного дива. Главное, выполнять код после полной загрузки сайта. В этом поможет событие window.onload

Comment: @Gelloiss - не выйдет. в виджете расписания вот такой код: 

`window.ContextRas.push(()=>{
  RA.Context.Manager.render({
    type: 'fullscreen',    
    platform: 'touch',
    blockId: 'ras'
  })
})`

Я только его вставляю на сайт, больше ничего, остальное появляется само. А то что написано в JS - blockId: 'ras' его нигде нет, я проверял

Comment: ContextRas должен где-то быть. Виджет же появляется в каком-то конкретном месте html кода, его можно найти